# Restrict android phone to just install just my application

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

I am building a android application and I want to run this application in such a way that once it is installed in a device, that particular device should not be allowed to install any other applications. Basically restrict app installation to just one application(i.e mine).

I have looked at few options such a home launcher and tried but this allows me to install other applications as well. Is there a methodology where I can block other apps from getting installed in my device? Thank you.

Comment: You can install a launcher replacement app like surelock (I have no affiliation with them) which allows you to lock down the device to only run white-listed apps. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock

Comment: well! it is. especially when we are dealing with field force applications where the employer hands over a device to their employees (who are on the field) and prevent the employees from installing other apps apart from the one given by the employer. It is a real time scenario mate!

Comment: You need to implement a "device administration" solution. Read about this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this page:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

When a package has been installed, you should receive a new broadcast event with this intent.
Basically, you have to force uninstall or lock the app with that package id. You'll probably need to be root on the device if you want to avoid a new activity to show up.